# How to union two counts queries in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have two queries and the only difference between then is that one is counting the success status and the other failure status. Is there a way to get this result in just one query? I'm using SQLALchemy to do the queries.

```
success_status_query = (
    db_session.query(Playbook.operator, func.count(Playbook.operator).label("success"))
    .filter(Playbook.opname != "failed")
    .join(AccountInfo, AccountInfo.hardware_id == Playbook.hardware_id)
    .group_by(Playbook.operator)
)
```

```
failure_status_query = (
    db_session.query(Playbook.operator, func.count(Playbook.operator).label("failure"))
    .filter(Playbook.opname == "failed")
    .join(AccountInfo, AccountInfo.hardware_id == Playbook.hardware_id)
    .group_by(Playbook.operator)
)
```

Comment: You can do a simple union with `q1.union(q2)`, but it might be difficult to distinguish between the success and failure results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditions on Count, your query will look like:

```py
query = (
    db_session.query(
        Playbook.operator,
        func.count(
            case(
                [((Playbook.opname != "failed"), Playbook.operator)],
                else_=literal_column("NULL"),
            )
        ).label("success"),
        func.count(
            case(
                [((Playbook.opname == "failed"), Playbook.operator)],
                else_=literal_column("NULL"),
            )
        ).label("failure"),
    )
    .join(AccountInfo, AccountInfo.hardware_id == Playbook.hardware_id)
    .group_by(Playbook.operator)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the or_() operator like the sample bellow:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

stmt = select(users_table).where(
                or_(
                    users_table.c.name == 'wendy',
                    users_table.c.name == 'jack'
                )
            )
```

It won't be a straight swap, but you will be able to work it out.

You can find more information in the SQLAlchemy documentation:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_